# sqlite db called from flask only returns variables, not values

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I have a flask app that queries a sqlite db:

```
@app.route('/<subject_id>')
def subject_id_lookup(subject_id):
    entries = query_db('select visitdt, cvnotes from exam where id = ?',
                        [subject_id], one=True)
    return render_template('show_results.html', entries = entries)
```

I am using flask functions largely unchanged from the docs including `query_db()`

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one = False):
    """Queries the database and returns a list of dictionaries"""
    cur = g.db.execute(query, args)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value)
        for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

Finally here is my show_results.html file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <ul class=entries>
        {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><h2>{{ entry }}</h2>
        <br>
        {% else %}
        <li><em>No entry here</em>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

The query runs fine but the nothing is returned except the variable names `visitdt` &  `cvnotes`.  When I change the line above to `<li><h2>{{ entry.cvnotes }}</h2>`, it returns nothing.  How can I modify my query to show results from my `subject_id_lookup()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `query_db` returns different things depending on whether you specify `one=True` or `one=False`.

```
>>> query_db(your_query, [some_id], one=True)
{visittd: "a value", cvnotes: "some notes"}

>>> query_db(your_query, [some_id], one=False)
[{visittd: "a value", cvnotes: "some notes"}] # Note the wrapping list
```

When you enumerate over a dictionary the result is the keys in the dictionary - when you enumerate over a list, the result is the entries in the list.

```
>>> for thing in query_db(your_query, [some_id], one=True):
...    print thing
visitdt
cvnotes

>>> for thing in query_db(your_query, [some_id], one=False):
...    print thing
{visittd: "a value", cvnotes: "some notes"}
```

If you want to use the same template and you know there is only going to be one value returned for one `id` (or if you are fine with dealing with more than one value) simply remove the `one=True` keyword argument in `subject_id_lookup`.  `entries` will then be a list of one dictionary containing the keys `visitdt` and `cvnotes` - when you iterate over it in your template each entry will be a result dictionary (rather than a key in the single result dictionary) and `{{ entry.cvnotes }}` will work.